# Ifconfig shows multople ip address i dont recognize

Tags: networking

I have multiple unknown ips running which point to a apache server (as0tx). What are these and how can i remove them?

```
as0t0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.224.1  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.224.1
        inet6 fe80::8bc0:463:daa5:baa1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 254  bytes 46313 (46.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t1: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.224.129  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.224.129
        inet6 fe80::d715:72eb:1a30:97a0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 254  bytes 46313 (46.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t2: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.225.1  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.225.1
        inet6 fe80::c455:f4ac:d5ec:3c4f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 254  bytes 46313 (46.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t3: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.225.129  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.225.129
        inet6 fe80::301e:1c0d:ff12:c4b4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 254  bytes 46313 (46.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t4: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.226.1  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.226.1
        inet6 fe80::bbf3:b15a:8974:a3d0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 254  bytes 46313 (46.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t5: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.226.129  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.226.129
        inet6 fe80::21f1:3c80:b64c:5968  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 254  bytes 46313 (46.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t6: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.227.1  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.227.1
        inet6 fe80::f305:f4bf:e427:3ab1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 254  bytes 46313 (46.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t7: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.227.129  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.227.129
        inet6 fe80::2326:9967:87ba:5365  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 254  bytes 46313 (46.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t8: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.228.1  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.228.1
        inet6 fe80::d971:eaa8:3f24:57b2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 254  bytes 46313 (46.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t9: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.228.129  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.228.129
        inet6 fe80::9ab4:bd2d:5f9f:4cfc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 254  bytes 46313 (46.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t10: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.229.1  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.229.1
        inet6 fe80::ba17:5005:b956:6792  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 254  bytes 46313 (46.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t11: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.229.129  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.229.129
        inet6 fe80::aebf:85dc:9af2:2453  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 254  bytes 46313 (46.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t12: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.230.1  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.230.1
        inet6 fe80::210c:d5b4:29e1:fb6b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 254  bytes 46313 (46.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t13: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.230.129  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.230.129
        inet6 fe80::3f40:408d:7e9a:a935  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 254  bytes 46313 (46.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t14: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.231.1  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.231.1
        inet6 fe80::de20:961c:71a6:c63a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 254  bytes 46313 (46.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t15: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.231.129  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.231.129
        inet6 fe80::e6d2:eb7c:d5f7:5c47  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 254  bytes 46313 (46.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t16: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.232.1  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.232.1
        inet6 fe80::6770:baa1:eca5:26e6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 254  bytes 46313 (46.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t17: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.232.129  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.232.129
        inet6 fe80::2b2b:99bb:be63:6a2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 254  bytes 46313 (46.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t18: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.233.1  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.233.1
        inet6 fe80::3ce4:669a:d765:cc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 254  bytes 46313 (46.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t19: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.233.129  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.233.129
        inet6 fe80::aed4:e1cd:27f4:5684  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 254  bytes 46313 (46.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t20: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.234.1  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.234.1
        inet6 fe80::9163:ce92:a5f9:4bce  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 254  bytes 46313 (46.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t21: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.234.129  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.234.129
        inet6 fe80::6c15:5877:757f:8811  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 254  bytes 46313 (46.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t22: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.235.1  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.235.1
        inet6 fe80::4acf:2519:39aa:1fa4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 254  bytes 46313 (46.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t23: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.235.129  netmask 255.255.255.128  destination 172.27.235.129
        inet6 fe80::6390:6360:f9b4:8b15  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 254  bytes 46313 (46.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:efff:fe8f:8bf9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:ef:8f:8b:f9  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 176  bytes 32998 (32.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3939  bytes 467810 (467.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3939  bytes 467810 (467.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.107  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::2323:6ff5:ce13:37d2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:45:e2:71:c3:29  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 248431  bytes 263960040 (263.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 237  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 91535  bytes 25605469 (25.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Don't worry: these are [non-routable IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network). They have been assigned to your interfaces by some process in your system. They do not point to any Internet server. However, I can't tell you how your interfaces ended up with these addresses.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really don't know what caused them. The only thing i can think of is openvpn.